# jQuery cookie issue

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using this function to get a cookie and write its value on an hidden field:

```
//WE NEED TO SET THE COOKIE IMMEDIATELY
var tuitting_cookie = $.cookie("tuittingID");
$("#tuittingID").val(tuitting_cookie);
```

The problem is that the Cookie is generated in the same page where this jQuery cookie function is.

So at the very first load of the page the cookie is not yet available.

What I need to do is maybe set up a time out function that will check the cookie every second and will write the value in that field as soon as the Cookie becomes available in the browser..

How can I do it? IS there a better solution..

Let me know

Thanks very much!!

P.S the cookie is generated by a PHP function. I cannot directly generate the cookie with jQuery. So I just need a way to check the cookie every second and write the cookie in that field as soon as the cookie becomes available in the browser.

Thanks again!

Comment: But how and when do you exactly generate that cookie?

Comment: I am suffering from exactly this issue.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that code in a  function and add it as a callback to when you set the cookie.